# How do I contrast code two separate experimental variables that share a reference variable?

Tags: regression, multicollinearity, contrasts

In my experiment, participants were recorded saying a target phrase multiple times. For some of the trials, there were no experimental manipulations (control). In other trials, we applied pitch perturbations that differed by direction (up vs. down) and timing within the phrase (early, middle). So each timing condition had both direction conditions (early-up, early-down, middle-up, middle-down). The dependent variable is an acoustic measure of speech production (acoustic).

The goal of the analysis is to see how each experimental variable compares with the control trials. The issue I am having is that I am unsure how to contrast code the variables since they both share the same control trials. This is how the table looks:

[image]

I am trying to run an analysis like this:

```
lmer(y ~ Direction * Timing + (1|subj), data = data)
```

However, there is obviously collinearity between the two variables because the control trials are the same with each. I want to analyze the main effect for each Direction and Timing but also the interactions between them (for example, upxearly vs. upxmiddle).

If anyone has any advice for how to organize or contrast code this, I will be very appreciative. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you never have any combination of 'up × timeControl' or 'early × directControl' then you can never actually compare the groups to the controls using a linear model with your data as is.

As far as I can see you have two options:

1. Do not fit any kind of linear model to these data and instead just make comparisons visually (i.e. make some graphs to show differences), or;
2. combine your factors to create a new single column. You could do this with:

`data$Treatment <- paste(data$Direction, data$Timing, sep = ":")`

This will make it a little harder to interpret, particularly for interactions, but as far as I can see it is the only way to fit a statistical model to these data.

From here you could use:

```
fit <- lmer(y ~ Treatment + (1|subj), data = data)
pm <- predictmeans(fit, modelterm = "Treatment", pairwise = T, adj = "holm")
```

The second line will give you a bunch of helpful statistics, provide you with all pairwise comparisons and as well as some plots to help you visualise differences. It also carries out a [holm-bonferroni](https://www.statisticshowto.datasciencecentral.com/holm-bonferroni-method/) correction to keep the [family wise error rate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Family-wise_error_rate) at 5%.

Comment: Thank you for your response! The issue is that the control trials in each column will always occur together. So it will always be control-control but never control-early or up-control. I changed the names of the control trials like you suggested but I still get the same error "Coefficients: (4 note defined because of singularities)."

Comment: Right you are - my initial answer was wrong. I think I have amended it. Let me know if you have any trouble.

Comment: Note: You could also exclude the control data, but this would make it a lot more shakey. Secret option number 3 would be to do a little of both. Exclude the controls from the model and just look at differences between treatments, but then plot the data with the controls. As is you will never actually be able to say whether it is direction or timing that is having the dominant effect because you never looked at them in isolation.

Comment: Thank you!! Combining the columns is a great idea and might be a good option to look at the interaction of direction x timing. It may be a little faux pas but I wonder if I could just run separate models for direction and timing to look at main effects, and then run this combined model to look at interactions. I agree that there doesn't seem to be any way to look at main effects and interactions in the same model as long as they share the control trials. You've been so helpful! thank you for taking the time to share your ideas and wisdom!

Comment: No worries. Separating them out is a great idea and I can't see any reason why you shouldn't. Good luck with it and feel free to give it a tick if it answered your question :)

Comment: Thanks! I'm new here so I'm finding my way around. I ticked it as correct! Thanks again for your help!